# Limit children pulled in jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

I'm extremely new to certain coding languages and I'm trying to teach myself as I go. I'm usually able to solve my issue after some research but I'm really stuck. I have a responsive nav system with submenus built with jquery, but on responsive views only the button for the submenu expands the subsection.

Existing code:

```
cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');

multiTg = function() {
          cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
          cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
            if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
              $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').hide();
            }
            else {
              $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').show();
            }
          });
        };
```

I played with it a bit, but when I made the following change, opening/closing a submenu would close the parent menu.

```
cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');

multiTg = function() {
          cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
          cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').parent().on('click', function() {
            $(this).children('.submenu-button').toggleClass('submenu-opened');
            if ($(this).children('ul').hasClass('open')) {
              $(this).children('ul').removeClass('open').hide();
            }
            else {
              $(this).children('ul').addClass('open').show();
            }
          });
        };
```

I think my question is how do I limit the children elements being called by the toggle function? Or did I just mess this up all entirely? Any help or pointing me in the right direction would be amazingly helpful! Thanks!

PS, the HTML for the nav:

```
<div id="cssmenu" class="align-right mobile-align-center">
<ul>
   <li><a href="link">Home</a></li>

   <li><a href="#">About</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">About The Org</a></li>
         <li><a href="link">Leadership</a></li>
         <li><a href="link">FAQs</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>

   <li><a href="#">Divisions</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Division 1</a>
         <ul>
         <li><a href="link">D1, Branch 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="link">D1, Branch 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="link">D1, Branch 3</a></li>
         </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Division 2</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="link">D2, Branch 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="link">D2, Branch 2</a></li>
         </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>   

   <li><a href="link">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. First thing: is cssmenu a jquery object, or did you mean to use `$('#cssmenu').find(...)`  ??  Please create example code on eg. jsfiddle.net including css you used.

Comment: Thanks @yezzz! cssmenu is a jquery object. The example is up at https://jsfiddle.net/AntoineThomas/agLsz43r/11/

Comment: Thanks. You said "on responsive views only the button for the submenu expands the subsection. ". That sounds like an issue in responsive (mobile) view, but it seems to work fine. Did you mean "the expand button only works on responsive views" ? Perhaps you could elaborate on the issues you encounter and in which browser.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not explaining it clear, if you click on "About" or "Divisions," it won't open the submenu- it only opens when clicking the button next to it. The second bit of code (the one I modified), allows me to click "About" or "Division" to open the submenu, but opening the "Division 1" or "Division 2" submenu under the "Division" sub closes the entire submenu. Here's the jsfiddle for that fork: https://jsfiddle.net/AntoineThomas/7r729q5r/1/

Comment: ah understood. I thought you only wanted to open/close using the spans and use the a tags for linking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second code is almost there, except that the click is propagating upwards, thus triggering a click on the parent menu item.

It's always a good idea to use console.log. You'll see that a click on the child triggers 2 messages in the console: https://jsfiddle.net/7r729q5r/2/

To stop the behavior use stopPropagation():

```
   cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').parent().on('click', function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
```

See around line 36 on https://jsfiddle.net/7r729q5r/3/

Also, you have a bug on your css, line 230, which causes the menu to disappear on certain widths.

Comment: Ahhhhh! Thanks so much! Definitely a lesson learned. Thanks for pointing out the CSS bug, too!

Comment: you're welcome. Read about event capturing and bubbling on https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-event-capturing_phase or find good resources on http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll check both of those out!